# Handling file in PHP, File Name Availability Check

Tags: php

i want to check file name using PHP.

is it possible to check whether there is a folder or a file which is same as search term ?

PS: Extension should be excluded

if user searches for apple... and if there is a file with name apple.php.. it should show name already exists

is it possible to do with PHP ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely, check out the File exists function http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Comment: PHP also has `is_file()` if you don't want to identify directories. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php